# Replace the character # with incrementally increasing numbers

Tags: regex, replace

I am working with text, and wish to replace a # character with an incrementally increasing number. The text looks like this:

Chap.2.#

Chap.2.#

Chap.2.#

Chap.2.#

And I am trying to get it to read:

Chap.2.1

Chap.2.2

Chap.2.3

Chap.2.4 and on up to triple digits.

My source document is Mellel, but I also have Nisus Writer Pro, and a host of other text editors such as TextMate, Atom, TextWrangler, Brackets, CotEditor, jEdit, etc. I have tried using Regular Expressions in apps that indicate availability of using that, but to no avail.

I have tried searching for #
then replacing with \i, or \1, or \1\i, or \1\i.

Can someone help please? I've read many other similar questions on SO, and other sites, bt I can not seem to get the syntax correct (plus the other examples are not close enough to mine to help me figure this out).Thanks.

Comment: Code is almost certainly a better solution for this.

Comment: Just because regex exists doesn't mean one should use it for everything.

Comment: Do you mean using perl or awk? I think I would end up with the same question about syntax.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use perl:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { our $i = 1; } s/Chap\.2\.#/"Chap.2.".($i++)/ge;' <chapters.txt;
```

Extension to handle multiple top-level numbers, incrementing the second-level number from 1 for each top-level number independently:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { our $h = {}; } s/Chap\.(\d+)\.#/"Chap.$1.".(exists($h->{$1}) ? $h->{$1}++ : ($h->{$1} = 1)++)/ge;' <chapters.txt;
```

To only find and incrementally replace the # character you can do:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { our $i = 1; } s/#/$i++/ge;' <chapters.txt;
```

Comment: perl -pe 'BEGIN { our $i = 1; } s/#/($i++)/ge;' <chapters.txt; I tweaked @bgoldst's response to the this, and it worked, as well as the longer version. Now, how would I phrase this if Chap changed (to read Heading, or, Section, as well as the second number, within the same file?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the code to increment the second-level number from 1 independently for different prefixes (Chap, Heading, Section) and different top-level numbers for each prefix?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The text does change, as well as the number: Chap.2.#, then Section.1.#), then Quote.11.#., with # being replaced incrementally in each case. I was going to just cut and paste the first solution, changing the text as needed, then realized that it'd be quicker to search for an initial name which changes, with secondary numbers which change, followed by the # which needs to increment by 1 for as many instances as there are "text.number.#". I am going to test the second solution you offered to see if it works well within text with just "chap.1.#, chap.2.#, chap.3.#. "

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this with PHP at the commandline with a file called convert.php which takes a  filename as an argument.  Note: no for-loop:

```
<?php

if ( count($argv) < 2 ) {
 echo "Correct syntax is: convert.php filename.ext\n";
 exit;
}

$file = $argv[1];
$contents = file_get_contents( $file );
$nu = preg_replace_callback('/\#/',function($matches){
                          static $i=1;
                          return $i++;
                          },$contents);
echo '<pre>',"\n";                        
echo $nu;
file_put_contents("bestNumberedChapters.txt",$nu);
```

So, it is feasible with PHP to replace all chapter headings containing a '#' with an incremental, numerical value.

Comment: How do I use this? I made a php file, named convert.php, and in Terminal (I'm on a Mac) I ran /hr ~:~ ~$ php /Users/~/Desktop/convert.php </Users/~/Desktop/chapters.txt; but I get a parse error. Is there some other way?

Comment: So, if I get your question correctly you have a file chapters.txt which may have multiple instances of "Chapter.2.#" and this is what your're seeking to convert to the specified format? Slightly different problem, so I need to revise the solution I offered.  I need to get back to you about that.